# How to setup node and cli in tron?

Tags: tron

I need to develop a tron node and tron cli in local server. I have followed java tron documentation but in java tron there is no cli. Then I moved to tron cli GitHub and I install all packages. I ran tron cli. Then how to run node and deploy contract in tron cli?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/andelf/rust-tron, it is a powerful cli tool for tron.

Contract dev [Doc](https://github.com/andelf/rust-tron/blob/master/docs/contract.md).